# What does of JSONObject.putOpt and JSONObject.putOnce in org.json.jsonobject does?

Tags: json, jackson

What is the functionality of JSONObject.putOpt and JSONObject.putOnce in org.json.jsonobject
or What does of JSONObject.putOpt and JSONObject.putOnce in org.json.jsonobject does?

Answer (score 1):

Here what I got from oracle website:

[image]

So, **put(String, Object)** will act without any condition. This means you can add duplicate keys(eventually replace the existing key in the JSONObject), and also add null keys/values by put.

The **putOpt(String, Object)** acts the same as **put(String, Object)**, but both the key and the value has to be non-null.

The **putOnce(String, Object)** method is also like **putOpt(String, Object)**, but throws an exception if there is already a key of the same value.